# variance of a sum of independent identical random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I am trying to proof the following:
If $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of discrete independent and identically distributed random variables and if N is a integer valued random variable which is independent of the sequence then
$Var(X_1+...X_N)=E[N](Var(X_i))^2+Var(N)(E[X_i])^2$
holds.

My try was:

$Var(X_1+...X_N)=E((X_1+...+X_N)^2)-(E(X_1+...+X_N))^2$=
$E[(X_1+...+X_N)^2]-(E[N]*E[X_i])^2$=
$E[(N*X_i)^2]-(E[N]*E[X_i])^2$=$E[N^2]*E[(X_i)^2]-E[N]^2*E[X_i]^2$

thanks in advance

Comment: You can find an explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgM16HNeC3o).

Comment: @RobertTheTutor thank you